# how to figure out the complex declarators such as Essential C++ Ch2.8

Tags: c++

here is code of example:

```
  const vector<int>* (*seq_array[])(int) = {
   fibon_seq, lucas_seq, pell_seq,
   triang_seq, square_seq, pent_seq
   };
```

i step by step to figure out the declare:

1. `*seq_array[]` is is an array of pointer
2. `(*seq_array[])(int)` is an function with `int` parameter

3.so the `const vector<int>* (*seq_array[])(int)` is a pointer function that return `const vector<int>` type with a `int` parameter.

If my understanding is correct,then i can't find any `return` statement in this function.
If not, anyone can pointing out my mistakes and give some direction about complex declarators.thanks.

Comment: Well it's not a function so wtf

Answer (score 3):

`seq_array` is i) **an array** ii) **of function pointers** iii) that **take an `int` and return `const vector<int>*`**. One of the simplest way of learning what's going on is to follow the so-called [*spiral rule*](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). IMHO, it's one of the best mnemonics out there, even if from 1994.

Comment: thank you let me know the rules,it's very effective.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of function pointers, so the stuff inside the `= { ... }` bit is a list of functions matching the expected signature; that's why there's no `return` statement: it's an array with values, not a function definition.